# Ruby Enumerable Collect Array still showing at end of list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, enumeration

I'm using Ruby enumerable to create an array of from another model. The method "companiesattending"

```
class Conference < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accountconferences
  has_many :accounts, :through => :accountconferences
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :accounts

  def companiesattending
    accounts.collect {|f| f.name }
  end

end
```

What's strange is when I put this into a view I get a list of items as expected and then some of of the members of the array at the end of the list still in an array:

The View Results

```
    <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
        <li>Company 1</li>
    </ul>

    <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
        <li>Company 2</li>
    </ul>
[&quot;3point5.com&quot;, &quot;Company&quot;, &quot;5.1&quot;, &quot;A O Coolers&quot;, &quot;Abo Gear&quot;, &quot;Access Fund&quot;, &quot;AceCamp.com&quot;, &quot;ACORN&quot;
```

/app/views/conferences/_accounts.html.erb

```
<div class="span5">
<h3 class="pull-left">Companies That Are Attending</h3></br></br></br>
 <%= @accounts.each do |f|%>
    <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
        <li><%= f %></li>
    </ul>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

/app/models/conferences.rb (Show Action)

```
  def show
    @conference = Conference.find(params[:id])
    @accounts = @conference.companiesattending  
  end
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<%= @accounts.each do |f|%>
```

Use this without `=`:

```
<% @accounts.each do |f|%>
```

`=` is the reason your code is displaying the array.

Answer (score 1):

`each` returns `self`, i.e. the object it was called on, and `<%=` displays whatever the expression inside of it evaluates to. The expression inside of `<%=` is `@accounts.each` which returns `@accounts`, ergo, `@accounts` is displayed.

If you don't want the array displayed, use `<%` which only *executes* but doesn't *display* code.